# Selecting latest revision of every object on a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure how i could achieve the expected result, but basically, what i need would be using max(revision)  and group by release_number, filename and server return the expected result. The intention is to use the result to retrieve the latest versions of every object on a given table. I'm using mysql by the way.

**Table content**

```
id    release_number filename        server    revision
18271 00.00.01       content.text    local     7530
18414 00.00.02       content_b.text  remote    7859
18415 00.00.02       content_a.text  remote    7955
18565 00.00.03       content.text    local     8186
18608 00.00.04       content_b.text  remote    8248
```

**Expected result**

```
id    release_number filename        server    revision
18415 00.00.02       content_a.text  remote    7955
18565 00.00.03       content.text    local     8186
18608 00.00.04       content_b.text  remote    8248
```

EDIT:

This seems to solve the problem, but i'm not sure if it is the correct way to do it, anyone with more experience could please confirm ?

```
select * from table where id in (
  SELECT max(id)
  FROM table
  GROUP BY server, filename
  HAVING max(revision)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the latest revision number for each filename and join the result back to the original table

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   yourtable a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(revision) AS Max_revision,
                          filename
                   FROM   yourtable
                   GROUP  BY filename) b
               ON a.filename = b.filename
                  AND a.revision = b.Max_revision
```

Or you can use `correlated subquery`

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable a
WHERE  revision = (SELECT Max(revision)
                   FROM   yourtable b
                   WHERE  a.filename = b.filename)
```

Comment: @Prdp Hello, could you check my edit to see if it make any sense?